# How to select a column in SQL only if non null values present?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in postgresql called `debt` that usually contains null values. I am using a SQL statement to export the data to a CSV file. When the `debt` column has at least one non-null value, I want to export the column. But I want it hidden when all the values are null. How can I accomplish this with SQL?

Here is the current statement:

```
COPY (
  SELECT
    e.name AS "Employee Name",
    e.title AS "Job Title",
    e.gross AS "Total Pay",
    e.total AS "Total Pay & Benefits",

    e.year AS "Year",
    e.notes AS "Notes",
    j.name AS "Agency",
    e.status AS "Status"

  FROM employee_employee e
  INNER JOIN jurisdiction_jurisdiction j on e.jurisdiction_id = j.id
  WHERE
      e.year = 2017 AND
      j.id = 564
 ORDER BY "Agency" ASC, "Total Pay & Benefits" DESC
) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: use filter in excel and exclude null values

Comment: You cannot.  A `SELECT` statement has a fixed set of columns.  If you want a variable number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL or multiple `SELECT` statements.  That said, having a variable number of columns would seem to complicate the data ingestion process downstream.

Answer (score 0):

select IFNULL(colname,"") from dbname